# How do you share php.ini for a webfarm?

Tags: php, configuration, iis-7.5, php.ini, web-farm

we have a IIS 7.5 webfarm (3 servers ATM) running php. Using web deploy we keep the servers in sync, but this only applies to the files used by the sites and the configuration of the IIS.

Is there a way to get the php.ini to be synced between all the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just use a filesync tool to sync the file over to each machine, to do this you would need to share out the folder with the config file/s and then you sync from one server to the relevant shares. This however does not tackle restarting your webserver to use the updated php settings

Comment: We where able to use web-deploy as our "filesync" tool.